# c# wpf export RichTextBox formatting to xml document

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, formatting, richtextbox

so in WPF i've created a RichTextBox and implemented the functionality to be able to format selected text (bold, undelined, font, etc...), but now i would like to export all of the formatting to a XML file, so when i would load it the loaded file would give me the same text with the same formatting. 
I think that the best way to do this would be, if i could find each place where there is formatting in the RTB and then save it as a text range, but i dont know if RTB has a method for finding if a part of text is formatted.

Here is what i've got:
xaml:

```
<Button Name = "export" Click = "export_Click"/>
<RichTextBox x:Name="RTB"/>
```

and the c#:

```
private void export_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    TextRange range = new TextRange();
    //here is where i want to access the formatted areas
    //something like: range = RTB.document.getBoldArea();
    //and then i could export what i got in the text range to a xml file
}
```

thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually access XAML content directly, which is itself obviously XML.  You could either save this directly or manipulate/translate it into your own schema.

To get the XAML for a RichTextBox :

```
static string GetXaml(RichTextBox rt)
{
    TextRange range = new TextRange(rt.Document.ContentStart, rt.Document.ContentEnd);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
    string xamlText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    return xamlText;
}
```

To set the XAML content for a RichTextBox :

```
static void SetXaml(RichTextBox rt, string xamlString)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
    while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
        doc.Blocks.Add(sec.Blocks.FirstBlock);
    rt.Document = doc;
}
```